# TimeTraveler for the Mac?

Tags: backup, windows-explorer, time-machine

Is there such a thing as [TimeTraveler](http://bearsontheLoose.com) for the Mac?

I know about time machine, but TimeTraveler is integrated with Windows Explorer. Something which woud interactively change the view in the Finder to a prior time that has a backup in Time Machine would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Time Machine already has this functionality. Click on the time machine icon in the MenuExtras bar at the topright while the backup drive is connected.

If that doesn't suffice, then you'll want to look at [BackupLoupe](http://www.soma-zone.com/BackupLoupe/) which is only $5 and will give you Finder integration and a bunch of other fun stuff.

Comment: I don't understand how to use the Time Machine interface quite the way I would like:  In TimeTraveler I select something in Windows Explorer and all the snapshots including the selected item (either a directory or a file) appear in the TimeTraveler window.  Now I just click on one and I can compare it to the current (or another selected version). Time Machine works the other way ... select a time and if the file is there you can open it. It does have a nice search feature, but I don't get to see all the snapshot times for the file.  Did I miss something?

Comment: No, that sounds accurate.